# IIS URL Rewrite Rule to Redirect Hostname to Subolder

Tags: windows, iis, windows-server-2016

How would I create a new rule for IIS URL Rewrite to redirect to a subfolder website when someone visits the hostname on port 80 http://.

Ex. user visits http://server01 or http://server01.company.com and they are redirected to http://server01.company.com/subfolder.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The  element configures settings for Internet Information Services (IIS) that redirect client requests to a new location.

In the simplest configuration, you need only set the enabled and destination attributes of the  element in order to redirect clients to a new location. However, additional elements like the exactDestination and httpResponseStatus attributes allow you to configure the end-user experience of the redirection by respectively specifying whether IIS will return the destination URL exactly as entered and which HTTP response code to return to the Web client. HTTP Redirection is not available on the default installation of IIS.

**Install "HTTP Redirection" IIS feature on windows servers**

- On the taskbar, click Server Manager.
- In Server Manager, click the Manage menu, and then click Add Roles and Features.
- In the Add Roles and Features wizard, click Next. Select the installation type and click Next. Select the destination server and click Next.
- On the Server Roles page, expand Web Server (IIS), expand Web Server, expand Common HTTP Features, and then select HTTP Redirection. Click Next.
- On the Select features page, click Next.
- On the Confirm installation selections page, click Install.
- On the Results page, click Close.

**How to add an HTTP redirect rule to a Web site or application through IIS Manager**

- Open Internet Information Services (IIS) Manager.
- In the Connections pane, expand the server name, expand Sites, and then navigate to the Web site or application that you want to configure custom error pages for.
- In the Home pane, double-click HTTP Redirect.
- In the HTTP Redirect pane, check the box to redirect requests and enter the destination URL.
- You can optionally specify some of the options there.

**How to add an HTTP redirect rule to a Web site or application through the `web.config` file of your site**

Open sour Web config and add it like this:

```
<configuration>
    <system.webServer>
        <httpRedirect enabled="true" destination="http://server01.company.com/subfolder" />
    </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```